# Setting default location for screenshots in Robot Framework using AppiumLibrary

Tags: appium, robotframework

I am using `AppiumLibrary` with `Robot Framework` and I want to set a default location for screenshots which were be taken when failure occurs.

The `Capture Page Screenshot` is the default keyword which will be executed on failure, but how can I set the default location for it?

I tried setting like this:
   `Library         AppiumLibrary   run_on_failure=Capture Page Screenshot filename=path/to/file.png`

In this case, the `filename` parameter won't be considered.

Answer (score -1):

Everything you need should be in the documentation https://serhatbolsu.github.io/robotframework-appiumlibrary/AppiumLibrary.html#Capture%20Page%20Screenshot

If you do not give an absolute path it is considered a relative path.

Comment: Yeah, I searched for a solution in the documentation but didn't find one, that's why I'm asking here. My problem is that if I use the keyword by it's own (not the case) I can set the location. But I want to register to run this keyword only on failure and if I register the keyword the `filename` parameter won't be considered and no screenshots will be taken at all.

Comment: Ok. Have you tried creating a keyword like "My Failure Capture" that calls Capture with the parameters you want and then specify that for run_on_failure.

Comment: Yes, I have tried. The thing is, `run_on_failure` accepts only `AppiumLibrary` keywords, custom ones are not executed.

Comment: Strange. Documenttion says "run_on_failure specifies the name of a keyword (from any available libraries) to execute when a AppiumLibrary keyword fails."

Comment: I tried it again, my custom keyword is not executed. I tried to log something, it isn't displayed on the console.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. My custom keyword won't be executed because not an `AppiumLibrary` keyword fails but my custom one.